# Calculate values in ranges for every row in table

Tags: mysql

I have table where some objects are described.

```
id title   low middle high
-- ------- --- ------ ----
1  Object1   2      5   11
2  Object2   2      6   11
3  Object3   2      5   15
4  Object4   2      5   11
5  Object5   2      5   11
6  Object6   2      5   11
7  Object7   2      5   15
```

So for Object1 values  0…2 should be calculated as lowCount , 3…5 as middleCount, 6…11 as highCount, all values greater than 11 as overCount.

Every object could get 3 values and it’s necessary to count how many values are in low, medium, high and over ranges

So For example with values  1, 4, 12 I expect to get the result

```
id title   low middle high lowCount middleCount highCount overCount
-- ------- --- ------ ---- -------- ----------- --------- ---------
1  Object1   2      5   11        1           0         1         1
2  Object2   2      6   11        1           1         0         1
3  Object3   2      5   15        1           0         2         0
4  Object4   2      5   11        1           0         1         1
5  Object5   2      5   11        1           0         1         1
6  Object6   2      5   11        1           0         1         1
7  Object7   2      5   15        1           0         2         0
```

For this issue I use the query:

```
SELECT
    `st`.`id`, `st`.`title`, `st`.`low`, `st`.`middle`, `st`.`high`
    , (IF((1 >= 0 AND 1 <= `st`.`low`), 1, 0) + IF((4 >= 0 AND 4 <= `st`.`low`), 1, 0) + IF((12 >= 0 AND 12 <= `st`.`low`), 1, 0)) as `lowCount`
    , (IF((1 > `st`.`low` AND 1 <= `st`.`middle`), 1, 0) + IF((4 > `st`.`low` AND 4 <= `st`.`middle`), 1, 0) + IF((12 > `st`.`low` AND 12 <= `st`.`middle`), 1, 0)) as `middleCount`
    , (IF((1 > `st`.`middle` AND 1 <= `st`.`high`), 1, 0) + IF((4 > `st`.`middle` AND 4 <= `st`.`high`), 1, 0) + IF((12 > `st`.`middle` AND 12 <= `st`.`high`), 1, 0))  as `highCount`  
    , (IF((1 > `st`.`high`), 1, 0) + IF((4 > `st`.`high`), 1, 0) + IF((12 > `st`.`high`), 1, 0)) + 2  as `overCount`
FROM
    `some_table` `st`
```

I don't like this construction

```
, (IF((1 >= 0 AND 1 <= `st`.`low`), 1, 0) + IF((4 >= 0 AND 4 <= `st`.`low`), 1, 0) + IF((12 >= 0 AND 12 <= `st`.`low`), 1, 0)) as `lowCount`
```

What could I use instead

Comment: consider providing a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` is acceptable.  The `case` statement is longer, but standard SQL.  However, in MySQL, you can also do:

```
select `st`.`id`, `st`.`title`, `st`.`low`, `st`.`middle`, `st`.`high`,
       ((1 >= 0 AND 1 <= `st`.`low`) + (4 >= 0 AND 4 <= `st`.`low`) + (12 >= 0 AND 12 <= `st`.`low`)) as `lowCount`,
       ((1 > `st`.`low` AND 1 <= `st`.`middle`) + (4 > `st`.`low` AND 4 <= `st`.`middle`) + (12 > `st`.`low` AND 12 <= `st`.`middle`)) as `middleCount`,
       ((1 > `st`.`middle` AND 1 <= `st`.`high`) + (4 > `st`.`middle` AND 4 <= `st`.`high`) + (12 > `st`.`middle` AND 12 <= `st`.`high`))  as `highCount` 
FROM `some_table` `st`;
```

In other words, MySQL treats "true" as `1` and "false" as `0`, so you can just add up the boolean values to get the counts.